# how to sort an array values by it key in angular2

Tags: javascript, typescript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opdhj.png)
i have an array as shown in image when user click on first_name the value of first name has to be sorted.if user click on email the value of email  has to be sorted

```
 ResultData =[{"First_name":"Raju","Phone":"9533993043","countryCode":"+91","order_datetime":"2017-5-3 11:13:49","status":14,"DeviceType":3,"orderId":"59096e3c320b2103820d855b","orderseqId":"E00002389","orderType":1,"CustomerID":"5908b6f6ee5df65f70fcdd81","pickAddress":"1-62/6, Gachibowli - Miyapur Rd, Laxmi Cyber City, Prashanth Nagar Colony, Kothaguda, Hyderabad, Telangana 500084, India","dropAddress":"1-`2/1/24/A/1,7,plot no 17, Hitech City Main Rd, Khanamet, Madhapur, Hyderabad, Telangana 500081,` India","pickLatitude":17.4566454,"pickLongitude":78.36482890000002,"dropLatitude":17.4535075,"dropLongitude":78.38307110000005,"paymentType":2,"itemDescription":"","receiverName":"Raju","receiverPhone":"9533993043","itemName":"Computer","deliverycharge":"199","bookingType":1}]
```

when i use below method i am getting sort array by First_name key only

```
sortObject(obj) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            arr.push({
                'key': prop,
                'value': obj[prop]
            });
        }
    }
    arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a.value - b.value; });
    return arr; // returns array
}
```

but i want to sort value by passing it key and object ..any plunker it will help me..

> Note:i din't get same key in my array

if i pass First_name as key 
then the value of first_name key has to be sorted..
if i pass pickAddress as key then the values of pickAddress has to be sorted.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, an example of expected output would probably help e.g. obj = {two: 3, one: 2} should output [2, 3]

Comment: you want to sort the object by keys or values?

Comment: i update my question.i want sort values of key dynamically

Comment: array=[first_name{b,c},last_name{ a,c,d} ]

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is your input and expected output. Example you showed is string now its a object.

Comment: i put a image to describe more my question